# What to do when SQL Developer randomly gets the ORA-12505 Error after some time?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I am currently using Oracle 11g Express Edition and SQL Developer 17.3, both in my workplace and my home. Both PCs are 64-bit, and run MS Windows 7. The PC at home always works ok, but there is a big problem in the PC in my workplace. After successfully connect the SQL Developer to Oracle and use it for some time, suddenly there is no response when running a query. I try to reconnect or create a new connection, but then the following error appears:

`ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor`

Then when I try to start APEX, APEX cannot be started either in Internet Explorer. The URL is http://127.0.0.1:8081/apex/f?p=4950 and the error `This page can't be displayed` is shown on the web browser. I try to click `Fix Connection Problems`, and the result is: `The remote device or resource won't accept the connection`, and `The device or resource (127.0.0.1) is not set up to accept connections on port "8081".` though obviously I am trying to connect to localhost.

Currently I have to save my work and reboot the computer. After a few tries, I found that the problem occurs usually after 1-2.5 hours after I start the PC, and sometimes I even did not do anything on the PC after successful connection, just left the PC idle, and then an hour later, the connection was lost. But some other times the connection worked for a long time without problem. Also, from the task manager, OracleServiceXE and OracleXETNSListener were both running even when the connection was lost. So I was thinking the ports 1521 and 8081 were blocked by some other software, or some software conflict exist, e.g. anti-virus software.

Since I do not have the admin rights on the PC in my workplace, I have to report the issue and let the support staff check it, but they have no clue because of the randomness of the problem. What are the possible reasons for the sudden loss of connection, and what should I check or tell the admin to check in this case?

Comment: This sounds like a listener configuration issue. Have you restarted the listener and confirmed that it's configured properly? What connection method are you using on the home PC vs the work PC - i.e. are you using a tnsnames.ora file at work, versus using a connection string at home? Any major differences in the connection info on your home PC versus the info on your work PC?

Comment: @solllodolllo My home PC has listener.ora, sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora, for the PC in my workplace, I have to check later. But the workplace PC must have sqlnet.ora, and both have the same contents: 
`SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)` but from my memory, seems like the workplace PC has only 2 .ora files instead of 3, it might be the tnsnames.ora file was missing when the connection lost. If that's really the case, would it be the cause of the problem? Since in my home PC, the default listener is XE and XE is defined in tnsnames.ora ... anyway I have to confirm. :)

Comment: Absolutely! Inconsistent configuration on the client side can cause issues like this, and your home PC having an explicitly defined listener could be the reason why the connection there is more consistent. To test this, you could copy the .ora files from your home PC to your work PC and see if the connection is better (YMMV depending on firewall/network rules.) 

The source of the problem could be a lot of things. If other people are also experiencing this, have your DBA(s) start with comparing the local and remote listeners. If it's just you, its likely a client-side configuration issue.